# How long does a smart contract typically take to complete?

Tags: web3js, metamask, pending-transactions, react

I have been developing an application using a smart contract, the application is similar to this one:
https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale

I went ahead and initiated a request, below is the codebase for it:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Message, Input } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Campaign from "../../../ethereum/campaign";
import web3 from "../../../ethereum/web3";
import { Link, Router } from "../../../routes";
import Layout from "../../../components/Layout";

class RequestNew extends Component {
  state = {
    value: "",
    description: "",
    recipient: "",
    loading: false,
    errorMessage: ""
  };

  static async getInitialProps(props) {
    const { address } = props.query;

    return { address };
  }

  onSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const campaign = Campaign(this.props.address);
    const { description, value, recipient } = this.state;

    this.setState({ loading: true, errorMessage: "" });

    try {
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      await campaign.methods
        .createRequest(description, web3.utils.toWei(value, "ether"), recipient)
        .send({ from: accounts[0] });

      Router.pushRoute(`/campaigns/${this.props.address}/requests`);
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message });
    }

    this.setState({ loading: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Link route={`/campaigns/${this.props.address}/requests`}>
          <a>Back</a>
        </Link>
        <h3>Create a Request</h3>
        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} error={!!this.state.errorMessage}>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Description</label>
            <Input
              value={this.state.description}
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({ description: event.target.value })
              }
            />
          </Form.Field>

          <Form.Field>
            <label>Value in Ether</label>
            <Input
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={event => this.setState({ value: event.target.value })}
            />
          </Form.Field>

          <Form.Field>
            <label>Recipient</label>
            <Input
              value={this.state.recipient}
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({ recipient: event.target.value })
              }
            />
          </Form.Field>

          <Message error header="Oops!" content={this.state.errorMessage} />
          <Button primary loading={this.state.loading}>
            Create!
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default RequestNew;
```

The button has a spinner that has been spinning now for over 20 minutes since the request was initiated.

I go over to Metamask and I am still seeing **Contract Interaction** in **Pending** status with a time of 21:51.

The last transaction I initiated the last time I was developing this application only took 14:47.

How long should it take? Is this the norm? How much longer should I wait? What are my options?

This is just testing on the Rinkeby Test Network by the way, so I am not so much concerned about loss as I am about time spent in pending status.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is happening there but in general when issuing a transaction it typically takes a second or two to get a response (a transaction hash). Due to gas limits I doubt any transaction can truly run for more than 10 seconds or so.

Comment: Check your Javascript console.  Most probably there has been some exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't used a high enough gas price.
Have a look at https://ethgasstation.info/index.php